# Query all collection documents and select data to query specific documents from another collection using Fauna and FQL

Tags: javascript, database, next.js, faunadb

I have a use case where I would like to query all connections from the `connections` collection, and at the same time find the right document using `employerId` and `employeeId` from their respective collections (employer and employee collection) using Fauna DB. So, if I get an employerId back from the query, I would like to get the data back from the document within the employer collection.

A document from the connections collection looks like this:

```js
{
  "ref": Ref(Collection("connections"), "336420921043583169"),
  "ts": 1657094868435000,
  "data": {
    "employerId": "330616765804445892",
    "employeeId": "330616700633350340",
    "isEmployeeApproved": true,
    "isEmployerApproved": true,
    "connectionAcceptedOnDate": "2022-07-06T08:07:47.846Z"
  }
}
```

I tried to create my function as the following, where I'm getting the data from the `connections`collection but I do not get anything from the other collections mentioned using the `employerId` and `employeeId`:

```
const getConnections = async () => {
  return await faunaClient.query(
    q.Map(
      q.Paginate(q.Match(q.Index("connections"))),
      q.Lambda("connectionDoc", q.Get(q.Var("connectionDoc")))
    ),
    q.Ref(Collection("employer"), q.Select("employerId", q.Var("connectionDoc"))),
    q.Ref(
      Collection("employees"),
      q.Select("employeeId", q.Var("connectionDoc"))
    ),
    q.Get(q.Var("employerDoc")),
    q.Get(q.Var("employeeDoc"))
  )
}
```

The ref I'm getting seems to be the first document within the `connections` collection. This is what I'm getting if I console log it:

```
data: Array [ {…}, {…} ]
​​
0: Object { ref: {…}, ts: 1656490913630000, data: {…} }
​​​
data: Object { employeeId: "330074643026149574", employerId: "331454006483222721", isEmployeeApproved: true, … }
​​​
ref: Object { "@ref": {…} }
​​​​
"@ref": Object { id: "335787295330271425", collection: {…} }
​​​​​
collection: Object { "@ref": {…} }
​​​​​​
"@ref": Object { id: "connections", collection: {…} }
​​​​​​​
collection: Object { "@ref": {…} }
​​​​​​​​
"@ref": Object { id: "collections" }
​​​​​​​​​
id: "collections"
​​​​​​​​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​​​​​​​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​​​​​​​
id: "connection_request"
​​​​​​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​​​​​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​​​​​
id: "335787295330271425"
​​​​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​​​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​​​
ts: 1656490913630000
​​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
```

How can I select the `employerId` and look up the right document from the `employer` collection? I would like to do the same for the `employeeId` and the `employee` collection in the same query.

**Updates**

A suggestion has been made:

```js
const connections = async () => {
  return await faunaClient.query(
    q.Map(q.Paginate(q.Documents(Collection("connections")))),
    q.Lambda(
      "ref",
      q.Let(
        {
          ref: q.Ref(Collection("connections"), id),
          connectionDoc: q.Get(q.Var("ref")),
          employerId: q.Select(["data", "employerId"], q.Var("connectionDoc")),
          employeeId: q.Select(
            ["data", "employeeId"],
            q.Var("connectionDoc")
          ),
          employerRef: q.Ref(Collection("employers"), q.Var("employerId")),
          employeeRef: q.Ref(
            Collection("employees"),
            q.Var("employeeId")
          ),
          employerDoc: q.Get(q.Var("employerRef")),
          employeeDoc: q.Get(q.Var("employeeRef")),
        },
        {
          ref: q.Var("ref"),
          ts: q.Select(["ts"], q.Var("connectionDoc")),
          data: {
            employee: q.Var("employeeDoc"),
            employer: q.Var("employerDoc"),
            isEmployeeApproved: q.Select(
              ["data", "isEmployeeApproved"],
              q.Var("connectionDoc")
            ),
            isEmployerApproved: q.Select(
              ["data", "isEmployerApproved"],
              q.Var("connectionDoc")
            ),
            connectionAcceptedOnDate: q.Select(
              ["data", "connectionAcceptedOnDate"],
              q.Var("connectionDoc")
            ),
          },
        }
      )
    )
  )
}
```

I receive the following error message when trying to use the function above:

```
InvalidArity: Map function requires 2 argument(s) but 1 were given
For more info, see the docs: https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/api/fql/functions/map
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is malformed: the `connectionDoc` variable is only valid within the `Lambda` function, yet you depend on it outside of the `Lambda` in multiple locations.

Also, you appear to store only the document ID of the connection document's `employerId` and `employeeId` fields, which requires you to reconstruct references every time you want to use those values.

Before talking about performing the desired lookups in bulk, let's look at performing the lookup for a single connection document.

When you need to fetch a document and the details of related documents, `Let` is your friend: it allows you to capture intermediate values, and compose an appropriate result. For example, to work with your example connection document, we could do this:

```
Let(
  {
    ref: Ref(Collection("connections"), "336420921043583169"),
    connectionDoc: Get(Var("ref"))
  },
  Var("connectionDoc")
)
```

When this query is run, the result is:

```
{
  ref: Ref(Collection("connections"), "336420921043583169"),
  ts: 1657556091310000,
  data: {
    employerId: '330616765804445892',
    employeeId: '330616700633350340',
    isEmployeeApproved: true,
    isEmployerApproved: true,
    connectionAcceptedOnDate: '2022-07-06T08:07:47.846Z'
  }
}
```

Note: My document has a different timestamp, because I just created my own copy.

So, `Let` allowed us to define a variable called `ref`, which was used to define the reference to the connection document that we want to work on, and then we defined the variable `connectionDoc` to contain the fetched document with `Get`. Finally, the result is just the value of the `connectionDoc` variable. So far, so good.

Now, we want to replace the `employerId` field's value with the values from the document that this document ID represents. Same with the `employeeId` field. To do that, there are two changes to the query that must be made:

1. We have to fetch the associated documents, and to do that, we have to compose references based on the available `Id` values.
2. We have to expand the response from `Let` to specify what values to return. Since the documents referred to by the `employerId` and `employeeId` field values aren't in the connection document, we have to compose a new object that looks like a fully-populated connection document.

```
Let(
  {
    ref: Ref(Collection("connections"), "336420921043583169"),
    connectionDoc: Get(Var("ref")),
    employerId: Select(["data", "employerId"], Var("connectionDoc")),
    employeeId: Select(["data", "employeeId"], Var("connectionDoc")),
    employerRef: Ref(Collection("employers"), Var("employerId")),
    employeeRef: Ref(Collection("employees"), Var("employeeId")),
    employerDoc: Get(Var("employerRef")),
    employeeDoc: Get(Var("employeeRef")),
  },
  {
    ref: Var("ref"),
    ts: Select("ts", Var("connectionDoc")),
    data: {
      employer: Var("employerDoc"),
      employee: Var("employeeDoc"),
      isEmployeeApproved: Select(["data", "isEmployeeApproved"], Var("connectionDoc")),
      isEmployerApproved: Select(["data", "isEmployerApproved"], Var("connectionDoc")),
      connectionAcceptedOnDate: Select(["data", "connectionAcceptedOnDate"], Var("connectionDoc"))
    }
  }
)
```

Note that, since you did not provide example employer or employee documents, I've created very basic documents with the same document IDs that you provided.

The result of this query is:

```
{
  ref: Ref(Collection("connections"), "336420921043583169"),
  ts: 1657556091310000,
  data: {
    employer: {
      ref: Ref(Collection("employers"), "330616765804445892"),
      ts: 1657556658720000,
      data: { name: 'FooBar Co.' }
    },
    employee: {
      ref: Ref(Collection("employees"), "330616700633350340"),
      ts: 1657556709680000,
      data: { name: 'Alice Lidell' }
    },
    isEmployeeApproved: true,
    isEmployerApproved: true,
    connectionAcceptedOnDate: '2022-07-06T08:07:47.846Z'
  }
}
```

Since the query has the entire employer and employee documents included, it is not necessary to include the `employerId` and `employeeId` fields in the result, since the references that include these values is already available. However, you could easily include those if you really want them.

Now that the query work for a single connection document reference, let's extend it slightly.

You didn't provide the definition for the `connections` index, but since your query uses it with no `terms`, and it appears that the index only returns references, it's a collection index, and is equivalent to using the `Documents` function.

```
Map(
  Paginate(Documents(Collection("connections"))),
  Lambda(
    "ref",
    Let(
      {
        connectionDoc: Get(Var("ref")),
        employerId: Select(["data", "employerId"], Var("connectionDoc")),
        employeeId: Select(["data", "employeeId"], Var("connectionDoc")),
        employerRef: Ref(Collection("employers"), Var("employerId")),
        employeeRef: Ref(Collection("employees"), Var("employeeId")),
        employerDoc: Get(Var("employerRef")),
        employeeDoc: Get(Var("employeeRef")),
      },
      {
        ref: Var("ref"),
        ts: Select("ts", Var("connectionDoc")),
        data: {
          employer: Var("employerDoc"),
          employee: Var("employeeDoc"),
          isEmployeeApproved: Select(["data", "isEmployeeApproved"], Var("connectionDoc")),
          isEmployerApproved: Select(["data", "isEmployerApproved"], Var("connectionDoc")),
          connectionAcceptedOnDate: Select(["data", "connectionAcceptedOnDate"], Var("connectionDoc"))
        }
      }
    )
  )
)
```

The only significant difference between this query and the previous one, is that the `Let` expression is embedded within the `Lambda` for the `Map` function.

Since I only have one connection document, the result is:

```
{
  data: [
    {
      ref: Ref(Collection("connections"), "336420921043583169"),
      ts: 1657556091310000,
      data: {
        employer: {
          ref: Ref(Collection("employers"), "330616765804445892"),
          ts: 1657556658720000,
          data: { name: 'FooBar Co.' }
        },
        employee: {
          ref: Ref(Collection("employees"), "330616700633350340"),
          ts: 1657556709680000,
          data: { name: 'Alice Lidell' }
        },
        isEmployeeApproved: true,
        isEmployerApproved: true,
        connectionAcceptedOnDate: '2022-07-06T08:07:47.846Z'
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

If you have more connection documents, there would be more entries in the outermost `data` array.

Comment: That is some really good information! It seems like the 7th line has a hardcoded id map function. How can I retrieve that value?

Comment: I'm still a bit noob, and I tried following along, but I don't seem to be able to create a function that works.

Comment: I've updated my description with the function I tried based on your information. Can you spot what I do wrong?

Comment: The problem, as indicated by the error message, is that `Map` takes two arguments: a set/array and a `Lambda` that can be applied to every entry in the set/array. You closed your `Map` call before including the `Lambda`. Check the brackets.

Comment: Apologies for the hard-coded ref. It's not supposed to be there. :-)

Comment: Hm, I tried my best but I cannot seem to figure how to do it right. Would you mind providing the correct function? I really want to learn this. :-)

Comment: I believe the hard-coded ref triggers me. When I delete the id it provides the following error message: "code": "invalid expression",
    "description": "Ref expected, Object provided."